# Help on this error "Failing immediately in simulator"

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Thanks for stoping by....

i have followed the below link to learn about the In App purchase in iPhone....

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-in-app-purchases/

when i run the code on xcode no errors found .

```
-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error  
{  
     NSLog(@"Failed to connect with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);  
}
```

but in the console i get the below error

> "SKProductsRequest: 0x5c0ec80>:
>   Failing immediately in simulator"

any help will be much appreciated...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In App purchases don't work in the simulator. Test on a device instead.

Comment: I think it's clearly more complicated than that. I was working on a branch for my project and In App purchases were working perfectly from the simulator. Now, I've merged to my trunk, things are a bit different. But my point is : "In App purchases DO WORK in the simulator".

Comment: That may well have changed over the course of the last 12 months ;)

Comment: Correct, it seems that InApp purchases WORK on the iPad 5.0 Simulator but DON'T on the iPad 4.3 simulator! Dear @user198725878, if you feel like updating the question and answer to have an up-to-date resource! ;) (uppercase is to attract attention of new readers on the up-to-date status, sorry about that)

Answer (score 0):

You can make work in-app purchase in the simulator. To do so, please refer to the following checklist: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/.

The trickiest part is that you need to upload a binary to make it work. So if you're in the early stage of development, you have to submit a binary, whatever it is, and reject it as soon as its status is "Waiting for review" to prevent it to get to the Store.